# SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online

So in a organization if some one wants to use SharePoint from the M365 Homepage it redirects a user to https://Domain.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/sharepoint.aspx and if we want to restrict general audience to other locations of the same site like

1. https://domain.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx?view=14
2. https://domain.sharepoint.com/SitePages/Forms/ByAuthor.aspx

General audience are able to go to that location but they get access denied error are there any alternative options to redirect all urls to one location "https://Domain.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/sharepoint.aspx"

Answer (score 0):

I’m afraid this is not possible with OOB solutions.

What I can think of is building custom solutions on the *accessdenied.aspx* and creation redirection to the M365 Homepage, since this page doesn’t allow customization directly (see a UserVoice post [here](https://office365.uservoice.com/forums/273493-office-365-admin/suggestions/17441431-edit-accessdenied-aspx-in-sharepoint-online)).